# XamarinForms ContentPresenter not passing viewmodel data to contentpage being displayed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, contentpresenter

As one of a few different methods for displaying ads on a page, I tried creating a `ContentPage` that gets instantiated as the parent class for another page.

Here is how the parent page is created called `AdFrame.Xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:services="clr-namespace:BoomStick.Services"
             x:Class="BoomStick.Views.AdFrame">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.9*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Frame Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red"  HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="200" />
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <services:AdView />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

`AdFrame.xaml.cs`

```
    public partial class AdFrame : ContentPage
    {
        public AdFrame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Then the page the is based on this parent.

`Home.xaml`

```
<d:AdFrame
    xmlns:d="clr-namespace:BoomStick.Views;assembly=BoomStick"
    x:Class="BoomStick.Views.Home"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    .......... />

    <d:AdFrame.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:FormatShortDateConveter x:Key="FormatShortDateConveter" />
            <converter:ConvertMonetaryFormat x:Key="ConvertMonetaryFormat" />
            <converter:BoolFromValue x:Key="BoolFromValue" />
            <converter:FormatNumberConverter x:Key="FormatNumberConverter" />
            <converter:ConvertLengthFromText x:Key="ConvertLengthFromText" />

            <DataTemplate x:Key="loadItemTemplate">
               ......
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </d:AdFrame.Resources>

    <d:AdFrame.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem
            Clicked="RefreshButtonClicked"
            IconImageSource="{Binding Path=RefreshIcon}"
            Text="Refresh" />
    </d:AdFrame.ToolbarItems>

    <d:AdFrame.Content>
        <ScrollView
            Margin="8"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              ...............
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </d:AdFrame.Content>
</d:AdFrame>
```

`Home.xaml.cs`

```
    private HomeViewModel viewModel;

    public Home()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = (viewModel = new HomeViewModel());

            InitilizePage();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DebugTools.LogException(ex);
        }
    }
```

In the code behind for this page however, if I call `InitializeComponent()`, then the parent page is never created, and only shows the page that called it. If I comment out the `InitializeComponent()` then the parent page is created, and I see the red and blue bars, but the content isn't shown.

As an alternate approach I tried creating a `ControlTemplate` that was the layout I wanted for the page, but the problem I had there is that the page being displayed in the `ContentPresenter` never get's it's `ViewModel` associated with it, so the page displays the XAML, but won't receive any data, or content that the `ViewModel` provides it.

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="AdEnabledPage">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.9*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Home}}}" Grid.Row="0" />
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Key=cBackgroundColor}">
                <services:AdView />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

When I was trying this approach, I would put this code into the page that I wanted the ads to appear on.

```
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            try
            {
                if (viewModel != null)
                    await ReloadPageData();

                if (!CoreGlobals.isPurchased)
                {
                    this.ControlTemplate = App.Current.Resources["AdEnabledPage"] as ControlTemplate;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DebugTools.LogException(ex);
            }
        }
```

How can I correct this, so that a page is shown inside of the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem. I had been basically trying to implement this using two different methods, taking half the solution from one and half from the other.
Once I figured that out,I was able to get things working.

I was able to make a fix by using code from a MS sample repository.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/templates-controltemplatedemos/

Cheers!